# JQuery Accordion not working when code seems alright

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#menu").accordion();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
                <p>I'm the first section!</p>
            </div>
            <h3>Sectio 2</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Tab 2</p>
            </div>
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Tab 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried several times but the page does not show up as expected in Google Chrome.Please could someone help me.

Comment: It looks good to me, check here http://jsfiddle.net/9Nmnu/

Comment: Don't see any issues there.

Comment: Funny! But mine refuses to work.I use NotePad++.

Comment: Notepad++ is just and editor, that has nothing to do with the code

Comment: Tried. Not working still.

Comment: why dont you try the same with jquery 1.9.2 instead of jquery 1.10.2

Comment: works just fine http://plnkr.co/edit/TsnUTUMuWFcRCc7Qy23F?p=preview

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: @GaurangTandon: Just saying that it doesn't work/not working/doesn't show up as expected will not help mate. It would be better if you explain what is the behavior you are expecting to happen vs what is happening and also mention any possible errors shown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `http` in your link to jQuery UI:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

It throwing error because the library is not loading properly.

Comment: Thanks! That got it to work. And thanks to all the others also.